# Selection of four distinct non-consecutive natural number

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Four distinct numbers are random. Four distinct numbers are randomly selected out of set of first 20 natural numbers. Find the Probability that no two of them are consecutive.

Let the sets A={1,2,3,4,...,19,20}
The number of ways of selecting 4 natural number is $^{20}C_4$. The answer is $\frac{^{17}C_4}{^{20}C_4}$ with no proper explanation provided. I would like to do this with inclusion-exclusion principle whereas we select 2 cases , 3 cases and then four cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without the inclusion-exclusion principle, since the form of the given answer certainly suggests that way.

First, select 4 arbitrary balls from 17 white balls that is lined up, by marking them red. Now insert one white ball after the first, second, and third red ball. This makes the total 20. Number the balls from 1 to 20. Do the numbers of the red balls satisfy the requirements (i.e. non-consecutive)? Do they cover all the possible cases?

Indeed, the "non-consecutive" requirement can always be removed this way.

Comment: Very nice explanation now is clear